# Ping statistics without stopping ping

Tags: macos, networking, ping

Is there a way to see a running-total `ping` statistic, without needing to stop and restart `ping`?

When running, I see this:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3758 ttl=52 time=32.387 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3759 ttl=52 time=30.771 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3760 ttl=52 time=37.255 ms
```

I want to know how many timeouts I've had so far. When I stop the ping, I get this information:

```
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3807 packets transmitted, 3190 packets received, 16.2% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 30.078/34.463/358.893/8.354 ms
```

How can I show the ping statistics without stopping ping? Is there another tool that's better suited to this?

I'm running `OS X 10.8.2`, currently using `BSD ping`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> during execution will show you the statistics without stopping *ping*.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to put that in an answer...?

Comment: I found this helpful, but I'm not using OSX, so I want to add that under Linux you have to use Ctrl+\ (to send SIGQUIT).

Comment: Ctrl+T also works for FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

Download,  install and use MTR - this provides a combined ping and traceroute, and is available for most OS's (including OSX).    It shows everything above, for every hop between you and your destination host and updates every ping.